What did Scott Lang mean by "living as a tenant of the state"?
In Scott Lang's memoir Look Out for the Little Guy!, he describes his two-year house arrest following the events of Captain America: Civil War in the chapter "Making Your House Arrest...a Home Arrest".
In this chapter, Scott writes (emphasis added):

Also, since being kicked out by Maggie and living as a tenant of the state, I didn’t really have any cookware of my own. Other than a lot of items I ordered to make food “for one.” Is there any phrase in the English language sadder than “Single-Serving Cake-Maker”?

The phrase "tenant of the state" caught my attention. I tried looking it up online, but mostly found legal and academic texts. From what I gather, it typically refers to someone renting a public housing unit from the government.
However, this doesn't seem to match what we see in Ant-Man and the Wasp. In the movie, Scott appears to be under house arrest in a pretty nice townhouse, which looks more like private property than government housing.
So what exactly did Scott mean by this phrase? Is there some context I'm missing about his living situation during his house arrest in Ant-Man and the Wasp?

X-Con Security Services: we put the pro in probation

A similar euphemism in Brit. English would be "living courtesy of her/his Majesty" because prisons are styled "HM Prison".

Another idiom is that "the state ... is going to pay your rent." The first thing that came to mind was the lyrics to the Kingston Trio's "Bad Man's Blunder": "When I was arrested, well, I didn't have a dime
The sheriff said, "Son, you're ridin' free this time
Where you're goin' you won't need a cent
'Cause the great state of Texas gonna pay your rent".

I believe he's referring to his living circumstances in the years before his house arrest: breaking up with his then-wife Maggie ("since being kicked out by Maggie"); followed by, as we see at the start of Ant-Man, spending time in prison ("and living as a tenant of the state").
After his release, he moved in with Luis, so his time under house arrest would have been the first time in a long time that he'd had a home of his own to fill with single-serving cake-makers, karaoke machines, and ant-friendly electronic drum kits.

That makes sense. I misunderstood the context, thinking Scott was referring to his house arrest since that's the main focus of the chapter. But you're right, he's actually talking about his time in prison. Thanks for clearing that up.

@galacticninja: Given the liberty of referring to prison as some sort of government-owned housing (as a form of wit); it's not impossible to extend that analogy to house arrest as well, as you're still in some form of imprisonment. Your house is not a literal government institution the way a prison building is, but due to your house arrest it can be argued (for the purpose of a quip, which this is) that it temporarily acts as one.

He seems to be speaking euphemistically about the time he was quartered by the state:

After infiltrating VistaCorp’s headquarters and hacking into the system so he could return the stolen profits, Scott went a step too far, committing a crime that cost him his marriage.
After three years behind bars, Scott Lang was released from jail.
—Marvel.com

The word "state" itself can mean "prison" in American English slang (especially underworld/prison slang), such as "state holiday" meaning a prison sentence. However "living as a tenant of the state" seems to be a nonce expression and not something attested in the real world.

I see. "Tenant of the state" is a euphemism for being in jail. It's interesting how he uses that phrase to describe his incarceration. I got confused because the chapter mostly discusses his house arrest, so I assumed he meant that too. Thanks for the clarification.

"state" as slang for state prison is based on the US penal system having state vs. federal jails for different crimes.  That's unrelated.  In Scott Lang's usage, it's just saying the government ("the state") was his landlord, i.e. he lived in a government-run institution.  It's not a standard idiom, it's just one-off wordplay.  And yes, @galacticninja , it's a euphemistic way to phrase it, although the literal meaning of the phrase is accurate.

@PeterCordes "Tenant of the state" has a long history of usage as a phrase. I definitely wouldn't call it a one-off wordplay. I would call it a standard idiom. I've certainly heard it used in multiple other contexts with the same meaning many years prior to Ant Man.

Another similar familiar idiom would be a "ward of the state", a person (usually a minor) who is under the care/guardianship of the government, usually because their parents are dead or incapable of caring for them (or an adult who is unable to care for themselves due to disability). They may be living under immediate supervision by a foster parent, orphanage, or other institution, but the overall responsibility for their wellbeing is being held by the state. "The" makes clear that the reference is to the government as opposed to a US state-level government (vs. county, federal).

@Makyen Those hits are literal; the state owns property for some reason which has tenants. There is no idiom there, at least no more than in any other completely literal phrase like "tenants of John down the street" (though it is surely idiomatic).
